# Copy Struct to Array of Structs Received as Pointer Argument in Function

Tags: c

I've got a function that takes as an argument a pointer to an array of structs:

```
void foo (int *StructArrayAddress)
```

Within the function, I then build a new struct that looks like this

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[10];
}myStruct;
```

What I would then like to do is copy that struct to my array of structs based on the pointer to that array that I received as an argument. Not having any luck with the syntax, or I'm missing something. Can anyone advise?
Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not sure I explained myself correctly, as I don't think the solution posted here is what I want to do. To clarify: there is some array of structs outside my function here. I receive the address of the correct struct element in an array of structs as an argument to my function. Assume the caller already took care of passing me the correct address; I don't have to index it up at all.

I then locally build a struct from some other data. I now want to copy this struct that I built locally to the struct at the location in the array that I received as an argument.

```
void foo (int *StructArrayAddress)
{
    struct
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        char c[10];
    }myStruct;

    a = 5;
    b = 10;
    c = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    //Copy local struct myStruct to location StructArrayAddress here
    StructArrayAddress = myStruct; //Something like this but I have the syntax wrong
}
```

I hope that makes more sense.

EDIT2: I may have just realized something that you guys have been trying to convey to me that I was missing: is a reference to my local struct needed in the argument somehow so that the format of the structure as I pass it back is known?

Comment: If the argument is supposed to be a pointer to an array of `struct`s, why is it declared as `int*`??

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code of your function?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: My thinking was that though its an array of structs, the address is still the same size, no?

Comment: That need not be. You're unlikely to meet a platform where pointers to different types have different sizes or representations, but that is allowed [but all pointers to `struct` types must have the same representation and alignment requirements]. However, if you pass in an `int*`, you can't use `ptr[i]` to access `struct whatever`s that are stored in the array. You'd need to cast the argument, but then, why not pass the correct type from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition should be like

```
void foo (myStruct *StructArrayAddress, int index)
{
     myStruct x;
     x.a = 1;
     x.b = 2;
     strncpy(x.c, "Test", 9);

     /* Now copy this struct to the array of structs at index specified by second argument */

     memcpy((StructArrayAddress + index), &x, sizeof(myStruct));


}
```

Comment: The `memcpy` could be omitted. `StructArrayAddress[index] = x;` is good.

Comment: x is a local variable and that will not be copied to the array of structures.

Comment: @KanwarSaad `struct`s are copied on assignment. Whether they're local variables doesn't matter.